# OpenGL:no matching function for call to 'glutDisplayFunc'

Tags: opengl

My operating system is mac. However, when I put this code into the Xcode compiler and run it. The console says "no matching function for call to 'glutDisplayFunc'".

```
#include "GLUT/glut.h"

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 200.0, 0.0, 150.0);

}

void lineSegement(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE);
        glVertex2i(180, 15);
        glVertex2i(10, 145);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow("An Example OpenGL program");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(lineSegement());
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`glutDisplayFunc` takes a function pointer as its argument. The syntax you are trying to use does not match that:

```
glutDisplayFunc(lineSegement());
```

In this statement, `lineSegment()` is a **call** to the `lineSegment` function, with the **return value** (which is `void`) being passed to `glutDisplayFunc`.

To pass the function pointer, you simply write the name of the function for `glutDisplayFunc` argument:

```
glutDisplayFunc(lineSegement);
```